# AngularJS "controller as" syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Recently, I started to learn AngularJS and decided to create my first AngularJS project.
However, I faced the problem when initializing controller in html code.

I receive the following error:

```
angular.min.js:60 Error: Argument 'MainCTRL as ctrl' is not a function, got undefined
at qa (angular.min.js:16)
at ra (angular.min.js:16)
at angular.min.js:50
at angular.min.js:42
at m (angular.min.js:6)
at j (angular.min.js:42)
at e (angular.min.js:38)
at e (angular.min.js:38)
at e (angular.min.js:38)
at angular.min.js:37(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:60(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:51e.$apply @ angular.min.js:86(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:15d @ angular.min.js:26qb @ angular.min.js:15kc @ angular.min.js:15(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:158a @ angular.min.js:114(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:23m @ angular.min.js:6c @ angular.min.js:22
```

I don't want to use $scope at this time, and want to proceed with this task with controller alias. With $scope it is working alright, however, I am very interested in solution of the problem in case of using "controller as" form

It's a part of the code, where the error exists:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="blog">
<head>
 <script src="template/assets/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="template/assets/js/controllers/app.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/assets/template.css">
</head>
<main ng-controller="MainCTRL as ctrl">
   <div class="stage">
      <div class="prog-lang-container left">
         <div class="prog-lang-container-inner">
            <img class="prog-lang-img" src="#" alt="#">
            <span class="prog-lang-name">
              {{ctrl.name}}
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
         ...
   </div>
</main>
...
</html>
```

It's my app.js file, it's very simple just now:

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('blog',[]);
    app.controller("MainCTRL", function(){
        this.name = "TEST";
    })
})()
```

May be I'm missing something in the code

Comment: which version of angular js it is?

Comment: @Neel, I'm using version 1.5.0

Comment: That looks right on the surface. Do you, perhaps, have a second `ng-app` in your HTML somewhere?

Comment: @Lex, no, I declared only one ng-app, that is "blog". It works fine by using $scope, however, it is very interesting for me, why I got error, trying to use controller with an alias

Comment: post entire js and html code.

Comment: Try referencing the non-minified version of Angular to see if you get a better error message.

Comment: @dfsq, I post all js code I wrote, and other part of html code is empty, I have angular usage only in this part of the web-site

Comment: Post entire html file. Posted code is okay. The problem is obviously in how you include JS into HTML.

Comment: @dfsq, I use it locally, added, look in the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand why this problem happens when using minified version, one of solutions was said in comments above by Lex, and it is to use non-minified AngularJS file.
Thank you, all, who helped.

Answer:

> Try referencing the non-minified version of Angular to see if you get
>   a better error message. – Lex

Comment: I appreciate that, but it's not really an answer. In production you will want to use the minified version so it's troubling that this was resolved by using the non-minified version.

Comment: @Lex, of course, you're right, however, in minified version, we can use $scope. It works fine, but I think, it will not be very funny, when coming from non-min to min, I will have to re-write all code from "controller as" to $scope method

Comment: `Controller as` syntax is pretty ubiquitous. Perhaps your minified version is messed up - where did you get it from? Are you using a CDN?

Answer (score 0):

I've copied all of your code and tried it with both cdn and downloaded versions of the minified 1.5.0 AngularJS files and it all worked. So, the issue is probably in the rest of the code that is not included (...) or the minified file. Try using a cdn to see if it makes the difference.

Comment: Ok, thanks, before creating this question I created a copy of the project and deleted all code from it, starting from very beginning, and got no errors, but when trying to do it in the original - error achieved.
At this time, I started to use $scope and what can I say is that I like both "controller as" and $scope, but with $scope I have to write a less piece of code
Under posted piece of html-code I have only footer with static html, so...this was the only place where I used Angular at that time not like right now))